# Seed in Entity Framework Core Many-to-Many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

how can one seed a many-to-many relation in EF Core, couldn't find anything in this area?

So this is the entities

```
public class Student 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public virtual List<StudentGrade> StudentGrades { get; set; }
}


public class Grade 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int Grade { get; set; }

     public virtual List<StudentGrade> StudentGrades { get; set; }
}


public class StudentGrade 
{
     public int GradeId { get; set; }
     public Grade Grade { get; set; }

     public int StudentId { get; set; }
     public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

so the official documentation says you have to have a joining entity defined (in my case StudentGrade) and this should be referenced within the entities that are in a many-to-many relation.
[Ef core documentation for many-to-many](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration).

Now in EF, you wouldn't have to do this, it would figure out those things, and so instead of having the join-entity, you would simply reference each entity into the other.

So how can you seed this type of relation in EF Core?

Thanks

Comment: Seed your students, seed your grades, then seed instances of `StudentGrade` that relate the two. Not sure what the confusion is here.

Comment: the confusion is, why there has to be a joining entity ? why should one have to seed 3 entities instead of just 2 and use the collection of one into the reference to it that the other holds ?

Comment: Because that's how it works in EF Core.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what worked for me was overriding    `DbContext::OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` with something similar to this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.Entity<StudentGrade>()
                    .HasKey(s => new { s.GradeId , s.StudentId });
    var students= new[]
    {
     new Student{Id=1, Name="John"},
     new Student{Id=2, Name="Alex"},
     new Student{Id=3, Name="Tom"}
    }

    var grades = new[]
    {
     new Grade{Id=1, Grade=5},
     new Grade{Id=2, Grade=6}
    }

    var studentGrades = new[]
    {
     new StudentGrade{GradeId=1, StudentId=1},
     new StudentGrade{GradeId=2, StudentId=2},

     // Student 3 relates to grade 1 
     new StudentGrade{GradeId=1, StudentId=3}
    }

    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasData(stdudents[0],students[1],students[2]);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Grade>().HasData(grades[0],grades[1]);
    modelBuilder.Entity<StudentGrade>().HasData(studentGrades[0],studentGrades[1],studentGrades[2]);

    base.OnModelCreating( modelBuilder );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've followed the custom initialization logic, as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#custom-initialization-logic), since my commitment is just data for testing and developing.

I like to do the seeding in a synchronous way, as you'll see in the code.

**Important**: Previous to this step, I do a 'commit' (*context.SaveChanges();*) with the entities data that I have to join, so EF will pick them from the DB with the ID inserted. That's nice if the DB backend has an autoincremental ID.

Following with your example (I've pluralized the dbSets), and assuming you have inserted the proper data

```
    var student= context.Students.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == "vic");
    var grade= context.Grades.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Grade == 2);
    var studentGrade = context.StudentsGrades.Include(a => a.Students).Include(b => b.Grades)
               .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Students.Name == "vic" && c.Grades.Grade = 2);
    if (studentGrade == null)
    {
        context.StudentsGrades.Add(new StudentGrade 
        {                    
            StudentId = student.Id,
            GradeId = grade.Id
        });
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I've just seen that it's better to put into the 'if' the first two sentences for saving DB accesses

Answer (score 0):

For more information about M2M and skip navigation properties: [The Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many)

Entities:

```
public class Student
{
    // initialize navigation property collection in constructor
    public Student() => Grades = new HashSet<Grade>();
    
    public int Id { get; set; } // PK
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    
    public ICollection<Grade> Grades { get; set; } // skip nav property
}


public class Grade
{
    public Grade() => Students = new HashSet<Student>();

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Seeding:

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Grade> Grades { get; set; } = null!;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ConfigureStudents());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ConfigureGrades());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ConfigureStudentGrade());
    }
}


internal class ConfigureStudents : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Student> entity)
    {
        entity.HasData(
        new Student{Id=1, Name="John"},
        new Student{Id=2, Name="Alex"},
        new Student{Id=3, Name="Tom"});
    }
}

internal class ConfigureGrades : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Grade>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Grade> entity)
    {
        entity.HasData(
        new Grade{Id=1, Grade=5},
        new Grade{Id=2, Grade=6});
    }
}

internal class ConfigureStudentGrade : IEntityTypeConfiguration<StudentGrade>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<StudentGrade> entity)
    {
        entity
            .HasMany(s => s.Grades)
            .WithMany(g => g.Students)
            .UsingEntity(
                 sg => sg.HasData(
                     new StudentGrade{GradeId=1, StudentId=1},
                     new StudentGrade{GradeId=2, StudentId=2},

                     // Student 3 relates to grade 1 
                     new StudentGrade{GradeId=1, StudentId=3}));
    }
}
```